# Find and tar files which are X hours old

Tags: shell

I am trying to tar all the log files of a specific folder which are X hours old, i have done it with X days and I need it for X hours.

```
find $DEST_DIRECTORY/*.log -type f ! -name "*.tar.gz"  -mtime +$hours -exec mv '{}'  ${DEST_DIRECTORY}/${TAR_DIR_NAME}/ \
```

Above code is not working for hours.

Comment: Have you tried swapping `mtime` for `mmin`? (and multiply your hours by 60)

Comment: don't  you need a closing `;` or `+` char after the `[\]` char at the end? Also, update your code to show how you set the value for `$hour`. AND use 4 spaces at the front of a line that you want formatted as code/data/errorMsgs. Good luck.

Comment: hours=$(($FETCHING_HOURS * 60)) is how i am assigning value to the variable. @Shelter. I have done the closing part with ;

Comment: yes I have tried it with mmin and cmin as well but its not working here @theduck

Comment: If you echo out your $Hours variable what value does it hold?

Comment: if FETCHING_HOURS is 1 then $hours will be 60.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

`-mmin n` to filter for files that were modified *n* minutes ago.

So in your example you should replace `-mtime +$hours` with `-mmin +$[$hours * 60]`.

Full docs are here: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html

Answer (score -1):

you should try this :

```
find $DEST_DIRECTORY/*.log -type f ! -name "*.tar.gz"  -mmin -180
```

180 refers to 3 hours and you can tweak it to your need